# emplyee salary calculation using python Error

Tags: python

i am beginer of the python programming. i am creating simple employee salary calculation using python.
**tax =   salary * 10 / 100** this line said wrong error displayed Unindent does not match outer indentation level

this is the full code

```
   salary = 60000

if(salary > 50000):
    tax = float(salary * 10 / 100)
elif(salary > 35000):
    tax =  float(salary * 5 / 100)
else:
    tax = 0

    netsal = salary - tax
    print(tax)
    print(netsal)
```

Comment: Python is whitespace sensitive. You can't write sloppily indented code. Read the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is self explanatory.

You can't indent your elif and else, they should be at the same level as the if condition.

```
salary = 60000

if(salary > 50000):

    tax =   salary * 10 / 100

elif(salary > 35000):

    tax = salary * 5 / 100

else :

    tax = 0

netsal = salary - tax
print(tax)
print(netsal)
```

Comment: i updated code above now no error diplayed but no output displayed Y Process finished with exit code 0 displayed

Comment: Exit code 0 means that it ran successfully.
It does not display anything since you ask for no display in your code. Simply add a
`print(salary)`
 (with no indent) 
to have an output

Comment: i add print(salary)   Process finished with exit code 0 y sir

Comment: I edited the code so you have it fully correct. Indentation are crucial in python, they are the structure blocks. You may want to take a moment to read about how this works

Comment: print(salary) just wring working with the calculation not working

Comment: thanks sir. what is wrong on my code it working now

Answer (score 1):

You just need to fix your indentation, I would suggest using an IDE

```py
salary = 60000

if(salary > 50000):
    tax = salary * 10 / 100
elif(salary > 35000):
    tax = salary * 5 / 100
else:
    tax = 0

print(tax)
>>> 6000.0
```